# Given the distribution of $X$, whats the distribution of $cX$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let's say $X \sim \chi_k^2(\lambda)$ with pdf $f_x(x)$ (i.e. noncentral chi-squared distribution). What can we say about the distribution of $Y = cX$ ? where $ c \in \mathbb{R}^+$

I know that $f_y(y) = \frac{1}{c} f_X(\frac{x}{c})$, but can it be expressed in terms of a distribution? That is, $Y \sim \text{distribution}(\text{parameters})$?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a [Rice distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice_distribution) with adjusted parameters $Rice(c\nu, c\sigma)$ assuming $c \gt 0$,

- $\nu$ is the distance between the reference point and the centre of the bivariate distribution and so scales linearly,
- $\sigma$ is the standard deviation of the distributions of the $x$ and $y$ coordinates and so also scales linearly.

Comment: I have updated the question. I was thinking of a noncentral chi squared. My mistake, sorry. Thanx anyway :)

Comment: @Luikin: That is a significant change to your question (for newer readers, it originally asked about a scaled Rice distribution).  Usually a chi-squared distribution and a non-centred chi-squared distribution do not have scale parameters, but if you said "a scaled non-central chi-squared distribution" then many readers would understand what you meant.